# How to test component callback invoked by child component callback in React with Enzyme?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, callback, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have the following application:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleChildOnClick}>{this.props.children}</button>;
    }

    handleChildOnClick() {
        this.props.onChildClick('foo');
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Child onChildClick={this.handleParentOnClick}>click me</Child>;
    }

    handleParentOnClick(text) {
        this.props.onParentClick(12345);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Parent onParentClick={(num) => console.log(num)} />;
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper way to test the `Parent` component. The `Child` and `App` one are not a problem, but the `Parent`...

I mean, how do I test that a click on the `Child` component is going to invoke the `Parent` click callback without:

1. ...rendering `Child`. `Parent` should be tested in isolation as a shallow render. `Child` will also be tested in isolation and if I do a mount render, I'm basically testing the click callback on the `Child` twice.
2. ...directly invoking `handleParentOnClick` on the `Parent` instance. I shouldn't depend on the exact implementation of `Parent` for this. If I change the name of the callback function, the test will break and it could very well be a false positive.

Is there a third option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While testing `Parent`, you can do:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { stub } from 'sinon';

describe('<Parent/>', () => {
  it('should handle a child click', () => {
    const onParentClick = stub();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent onParentClick={onParentClick} />);
    wrapper.find("Child").prop('onChildClick')('foo');
    expect(onParentClick.callCount).to.be.equal(1);
    // You can also check if the 'foo' argument was passed to onParentClick
  });
});
```

Comment: Enzyme's `find` method accepts a React class as a selector, so you probably want to remove the quotes around `Child` (line 8). Aside from that, this is nearly verbatim that the answer I would give

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thank you very much =) @JordanBonitatis That will require an additional import while the quote example won't. Besides a string being more error prone, is there any other advantage in passing a class vs a string as a selector?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in the case when the child class is a MaterialUI component. Any ideas off the top of your head why?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could give you some idea.

// Component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleChildOnClick} className="t-btn">{this.props.children}</button>;
  }
  handleChildOnClick() {
    this.props.onChildClick('foo');
  }
}
```

// Test

```
import { spy, stub } from 'sinon';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Child Component', () => {
  it('should check handle click', () => {
    spy(Child.prototype, 'handleChildOnClick');
    const onChildClick = stub();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child onChildClick={onChildClick}>);
    wrapper.find(".t-btn").simulate('click');
    expect(Child.prototype.handleChildOnClick.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });

  it('should check onChildClick', () => {
    const onChildClick = stub();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child onChildClick={onChildClick}>);
    wrapper.find(".t-btn").simulate('click');
    expect(onChildClick.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

To test parent with child component

```
import { stub } from 'sinon';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Child from '../Components/Child';

describe('Parent Component', () => {
  it('should check handle click', () => {
    const onParentClick = stub();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent onParentClick={onParentClick} />);
    wrapper.find(".t-btn").simulate('click');
    expect(Child.prototype.handleChildOnClick.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });

  it('should check onChildClick', () => {
    const onChildClick = stub();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child onChildClick={onChildClick}>);
    wrapper.find(Child).prop('onChildClick')('foo');
    expect(onParentClick.callCount).to.be.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Above code just handle only one component, but I hope this could give you some gist. Sorry if the syntax is breaking anywhere..

Comment: This was not the answer I was looking for... You're just testing the `Child` component, not the `Parent` one (which the question was about). Thank for you contribution though.